# How to configure dynamically cakephp applications with nginx?

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

My problem is: I'm trying to configure a nginx with multiple cakephp applications (that will be added and removed from time to time). And I want to this configuration to be dynamic (if the subdirectory exists, then it will be loaded as a cakephp application, if not, 404).

But the thing is: I cannot configure the nginx to serve correctly the root for each application (i do not want to put every location on my conf file).

Ex:

```
/var/www/cakephp1 + /app/webroot/ Will be served as: www.mydomain.com/cakephp1
/var/www/cakephp2 + /app/webroot/ Will be served as: www.mydomain.com/cakephp2
```

I know how to make a configuration to run a single app. Any ideas how to achieve this? With dynamic configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for this easily. If you match anything in your `location` directive, you can reuse any part of the matching group in your `try_files` directives to try multiple locations. Also, you can use things such as `$http_host` to compose a different app root.